# How do I set an environment variables file on the command line?

Tags: shell-script, shell, environment-variables

I have a file .env.local that contains a set of environment variables that should be loaded when launching my shell script, is there a way to specify this file in the command line ?

.env.local

```
ONEDRIVE_TENANT_ID=...
ONEDRIVE_CLIENT_ID=...
ONEDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET=...
```

shell script: script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TENANT_ID=${ONEDRIVE_TENANT_ID}
CLIENT_ID=${ONEDRIVE_CLIENT_ID}
CLIENT_SECRET=${ONEDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET}
REDIRECT_URI=${ONEDRIVE_REDIRECT_URI}
curl REDIRECT_URI ...
```

I already tried : `source .env.local; sh script.sh` But it didn't work as expected! 
Ps, I can't add source inside the script because the script will be running in many environments so the absolute path of .env.local depends on the environment.

Comment: can you use `export VAR=Value` in .env.local file ? Otherwise there is the ugly,unsecure and bug prone  `eval $(< .env.local) script.sh` solution.

Comment: For `sh` `source` is typically spelled `.`. Your command should work. When you don't want to modify the script, then you could try `(. .env.local; sh script.sh)`. So that environment is valid only during execution of `script.sh`. Also see `man env` how to examine your environment.

Comment: As @Archemar pointed out, you need `export` to define environment variables; otherwise you have plain local shell variables (that will work only if you source them into the script directly).

Comment: Your script will somehow have to locate the environment variable file. If you can't figure out how to locate it, the script isn't going to be able to load it.

Answer (score 4):

You could set `BASH_ENV` to point to your dot-script with variable assignments.  Doing so would cause it to be sourced automatically before your script is run, making the shell variables available in your script.

```bsh
BASH_ENV=path/to/.env.local ./script.sh
```

If `script.sh` is a `bash` script, it would then have access to the variables (and functions etc.) from the `.env.local` dot-script.

From the `bash` manual:

> `BASH_ENV`
> If this parameter is set when `bash` is executing a shell script,
> its value is interpreted as a filename containing commands to
> initialize the shell, as in `~/.bashrc`.  The value of `BASH_ENV` is
> subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and
> arithmetic expansion before being interpreted as a filename.
> `PATH` is not used to search for the resultant filename.

---

Note that your script is *not* executed by `bash` if you use an explicit interpreter for some other scripting language, like `sh`, on the command line (like you seem to be doing in your question).

Answer (score 2):

`source .env.local; sh script.sh` would run `.env.local` in the context of the parent shell, not in the context of `script.sh`. Regular shell variables set there would not be visible to do the child. You'll need to explicitly `export` them.

Make `.env.local` look like this:

```
export ONEDRIVE_TENANT_ID=...
export ONEDRIVE_CLIENT_ID=...
export ONEDRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET=...
```

Comment: Or `set -a` before source-ing, and `set +a` after (unless you want to keep the behavior of auto-exporting everything)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call a `source "file.env.local"` inside the script (edit: and before you call the variables/arrays)

or this could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file-of-key-value-pairs

Comment: I can't add source inside the script because the script will be running in many environments so the absolute path of .env.local it depend of the environment.